# How do websites get this almost white color?

Tags: html, css, background

The background of a lot of websites is not actually white: it's more of a greyish color:

[image]

How do they do this? Is it just a picture they made or is there some CSS?

Comment: try using background color `#fefefe`

Comment: `#f0f0f0` or `rgb(240,240,240)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer:** Picture and CSS: *both* are possible.

**Long answer:**

To add a **background image**, you will have to do something like

```
body {
    background-image: url('bgpic.png');
}
```

where `bgpic.png` is the image that you want to use as a background.

I believe using a background image for a simple background as this one will only increase your loading time, and in turn, frustrate your users. The CSS alternative is faster and easier, as you might have probably guessed from the other answers.

In **CSS**, you can style your background like this:

```
body {
    background-color: #efefef;
}
```

Or, as someone pointed out, use the `rgb` equivalent:

```
body {  
    background-color: rgb(239, 239, 239);
}
```

And might I add that it is also possible to specify the transparency of the background. Say, you have a background picture, and you have a `<div class="foo">` that could use a semi-transparent background; then you would do something like:

```
body {
    background-image: url('bgpic.png');
}

.foo {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

Notice that the last value given to `rgba` is the `%` transparency that you want. It is a value less than `1`.

Here's a **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/X5kDz/)**.

Comment: @chipperyman573: Happy to help `:)` But please remember that you **must** search Google, and SO before asking a question. And read up on CSS: search for CSS Tutorial on Google. Avoid w3schools.com; See w3fools.com to know why. All the best `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ccnZt/

```
body {
   background: rgb(248,248,248);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just CSS.

```
body {
    background: #f0f0f0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if the website does not specify a background color, your browser will display a default color. Older browsers used grey colors, while new browsers use white.

Answer (score 0):

They could have used either a picture image or CSS; either setting the background image with an image of that solid color or setting the background color with RBG colors through CSS.

```
body {
    background-image: url('yourbgimage.jpg');
}
```

or

```
body {
background: rgb(244,244,244);
}
```

If you want to set your background to this color (or any other solid colors), it's better to go with CSS as it will load faster and improve the user experience!